# How can Javascript detect img content of div changed by CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, css

Any suggestions on how I can detect that the img content of a div has been changed via a CSS animation?

Pseudo code:

```
HTML
   <div id="banana"></div>

CSS
   #banana {
      content: url("image0.png");
      animation: blink 10s infinite;
   }

   @keyframes blink {
      20% {  content: url("image1.png"); }
      40% {  content: url("image2.png"); }
      60% {  content: url("image3.png"); }
   }
```

I've tried MutationObserver but that doesn't seem to get called when the animation changes the image.

I've also tried addEventListener('animationiteration'...) but that only gets called once around the loop and the CSS replaces multiple images (variable number with variable dispositions).

There is a note on the Mozilla dev pages about using "content:url(...)" - "CSS-generated content is not included in the DOM".

Does this mean it's not possible for Javascript to detect these changes?